# I'm trying to understand getchar() != EOF

Tags: c, eof, getchar, putchar

I'm reading The C Programming Language and have understood everything so far.
However when I came across the `getchar()` and `putchar()`, I failed to understand what is their use, and more specifically, what the following code does.

```
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
       putchar(c);
}
```

I understand the `main()` function, the declaration of the integer `c` and the `while` loop. Yet I'm confused about the condition inside of the `while` loop. What is the input in this C code, and what is the output.

Comment: It just echoes back what you type into the terminal.  Until you hit the end-of-input control code.  Ctrl+Z on Windows, Ctrl+D on *nix.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This code can be written more clearly as:

```
main()
{
    int c;
    while (1) {
        c = getchar();            // Get one character from the input
        if (c == EOF) { break; }  // Exit the loop if we receive EOF ("end of file")
        putchar(c);               // Put the character to the output
    }
}
```

The `EOF` character is received when there is no more input.  The name makes more sense in the case where the input is being read from a real file, rather than user input (which is a special case of a file).

---

[As an aside, generally the `main` function should be written as `int main(void)`.]

Comment: @TheGameiswar please read my new [addition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579071/918959) too.

Comment: `EOF` is not a character.

Answer (score 28):

`getchar()` is a function that reads a character from **standard input**. `EOF` is a special character used in **C** to state that the **END OF FILE** has been reached.

Usually you will get an `EOF` character returning from `getchar()` when your standard input is other than console (i.e., a file).

If you run your program in unix like this:

```
$ cat somefile | ./your_program
```

Then your `getchar()` will return every single character in `somefile` and `EOF` as soon as `somefile` ends.

If you run your program like this:

```
$ ./your_program
```

And send a `EOF` through the console (by hitting `CTRL+D` in Unix or CTRL+Z in Windows), then `getchar()` will also returns `EOF` and the execution will end.

Comment: Nice example on polymorphism using `getchar()`. Reads from the file(input). Reads from the keyboard(input)

Comment: you can even `./your_program < input_file`

Answer (score 9):

The code written with current C standards should be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
       putchar(c);
}
```

The loop could be rewritten as

```
int c;
while (1) {
    c = getchar();
    if (c != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    else
        break;
}
```

this reads as

- repeat forever

  - get the next character ("byte") of input from [*standard input*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540425/what-is-standard-input) and store it into `c`
  - if no exceptional condition occurred while reading the said character

    - then output the character stored into `c` into *standard output*
  - else

    - break the loop

Many programming languages handle exceptional conditions through *raising exceptions* that break the normal program flow. C does no such thing. Instead, functions that can fail have a return value and any exceptional conditions are signalled by a special return value, which you need to check from the documentation of the given function. In case of `getchar`, the documentation from the C11 standard says ([C11 7.21.7.6p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.6p3)):

> 3. The `getchar` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by `stdin`. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and `getchar` returns `EOF`. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and `getchar` returns `EOF`.

It is stated elsewhere that `EOF` is an integer constant that is < 0, and any ordinary return value is >= 0 - the `unsigned char` zero-extended to an `int`.

The stream being at end-of-file means that all of the input has been consumed. For standard input it is possible to cause this from keyboard by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Unix/Linux terminals and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in Windows console windows. Another possibility would be for the program to receive the input from a file or a pipe instead of from keyboard - then end-of-file would be signalled whenever that input were fully consumed, i.e.

```
cat file | ./myprogram
```

or

```
./myprogram < file
```

---

As the above fragment says, there are actually two different conditions that can cause `getchar` to return `EOF`: either the *end-of-file* was reached, *or* an actual error occurred. This cannot be deduced from the return value alone. Instead you must use the functions `feof` and `ferror`. `feof(stdin)` would return a true value if end-of-file was reached on the standard input. `ferror(stdin)` would return true if an error occurred.

If an actual error occurred, the variable `errno` defined by `<errno.h>` would contain the error code; the function `perror` can be used to automatically display a human readable error message with a prefix. Thus we could expand the example to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h> // for the definition of errno
#include <stdlib.h> // for exit()
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
       putchar(c);

    if (feof(stdin)) {
        printf("end-of-file reached\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (ferror(stdin)) {
        printf("An error occurred. errno set to %d\n", errno);
        perror("Human readable explanation");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("This should never happen...\n");
        exit('?');
    }
}
```

To trigger the end-of-file, one would use Ctrl+D (here displayed as `^D`) on a new line on Linux:

```
% ./a.out
Hello world
Hello world
^D
end-of-file reached
```

(notice how the *input* here is line-buffered, so the input is not interleaved within the line with output).

Likewise, we can get the same effect by using a pipeline.

```
% echo Hello world | ./a.out
Hello world
end-of-file reached
```

To trigger an error is a bit more tricky. In `bash` and `zsh` shells the standard input can be *closed* so that it doesn't come from anywhere, by appending `<&-` to the command line:

```
% ./a.out <&-
An error occurred. errno set to 9
Human readable explanation: Bad file descriptor
```

*Bad file descriptor*, or `EBADF` means that the *standard input* - file descriptor number 0 was invalid, as it was not opened at all.

Another fun way to generate an error would be to read the standard input from a *directory* - this causes errno to be set to `EISDIR` on Linux:

```
% ./a.out < / 
An error occurred. errno set to 21
Human readable explanation: Is a directory
```

---

Actually the return value of `putchar` should be checked too - it likewise 
returns `EOF` on error, or the character written:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (putchar(c) == EOF) {
        perror("putchar failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

And now we can test this by redirecting the standard output to `/dev/full` - however there is a gotcha - since standard output is buffered we need to write *enough* to cause the buffer to flush right away and not at the end of the program. We get infinite zero bytes from `/dev/zero`:

```
 % ./a.out < /dev/zero > /dev/full
 putchar failed: No space left on device
```

---

P.S. it is very important to always use a variable of type *`int`* to store the return value of `getchar()`. Even though it reads a *character*, [using `signed`/`unsigned`/plain `char` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/918959).

Comment: @TonyTannous have to ride the bounty :D

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help

Answer (score 6):

[getchar()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/getchar)  function reads a character from the keyboard (ie, `stdin`)

In the condition inside the given `while` loop, `getchar()` is called before each iteration and the received value is assigned to the integer `c`.

Now, it must be understood that in C, the standard input (`stdin`) is [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr) a file. ie, the input is buffered. Input will stay in the buffer till it is actually consumed.
`stdin` is actually the [standard input stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

`getchar()` returns the the next available value in the input buffer.

The program essentially displays whatever that was read from the keyboard; including white space like `\n` (newline), space, etc.

ie, the input is the input that the user provides via the keyboard (`stdin` usually means keyboard).
And the output is whatever we provide as input.

The input that we provide is read character by character & treated as characters even if we give them as numbers.

`getchar()` will return `EOF` only if the end of file is reached. The ‘file’ that we are concerned with here is the `stdin` itself (standard input).

Imagine a file existing where the input that we provide via keyboard is being stored. That’s `stdin`.
This ‘file’ is like an [infinite file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197123/5375464). So no `EOF`.

If we provide more input than that `getchar()` can handle at a time (before giving it as input by pressing   enter), the extra values will still be stored in the input buffer unconsumed.
The  `getchar()` will read the first character from the input, store it in `c and print`c`with`putchar(c)`.

During the next iteration of the `while` loop, the extra characters given during the previous iteration which are still in `stdin` are taken during  `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` with the `c=getchar()` part.
Now the same process is repeated till there is nothing left in the input buffer.

This makes it look as if `putchar()` is returning a string instead of a single character at a time if more than one character is given as input during an iteration.

Eg: if input was
`abcdefghijkl`
the output would’ve been the same
`abcdefghijkl`

If you don’t want this behaviour, you can add [fflush(stdin);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170410/what-is-the-use-of-fflushstdin-in-c-programming) right after the `putchar(c);`.
This will cause the loop to print only the first character in the input provided during each iteration.

Eg: if input was 
`adgbad` 
only `a` will be printed.

The input is sent to `stdin` only after you press enter.

[putchar()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/getchar) is the opposite of `getchar()`. It writes the output to the standard output stream (`stdout`, usually the monitor).

`EOF` is not a character present in the file. It’s something returned by the function as an error code.

You probably won’t be able to exit from the give `while` loop normally though. The input buffer will emptied (for displaying to the output) as soon as something comes into it via keyboard and the `stdin` won't give `EOF`.

For manually exiting the loop, `EOF` can be sent using keyboard by pressing
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in Linux and
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in Windows

eg:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{

   putchar(c);
   fflush(stdin);
}
printf("\nGot past!");
```

If you press the key combination to give `EOF`, the message `Got past!` will be displayed before exiting the program.

If `stdin` is *not* already empty, you will have to press this key combination twice. Once to clear this buffer and then to simuate `EOF`.

EDIT: The extra pair of parenthesis around `c = getchar()` in `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` is to make sure that the value returned by `getchar()` is first assigned to `c` before *that* value is compared with `EOF`.

If this extra parenthesis were not there, the expression would effectively have been `while (c = (getchar() != EOF) )` which would've meant that `c` could have either of 2 values: `1` (for true) or `0` (for false) which is obviously not what is intended.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you got confused by the fact that entering -1 on the command line does not end your program? Because `getchar()` reads this as two chars, - and 1. In the assignment to c, the character is converted to the ASCII numeric value. This numeric value is stored in some memory location, accessed by c.

Then `putchar(c)` retrieves this value, looks up the ASCII table and converts back to character, which is printed.

I guess finding the value -1 decimal in the ASCII table is impossible, because the table starts at 0. So `getchar()` has to account for the different solutions at different platforms. maybe there is a `getchar()` version for each platform?

I just find it strange that this EOF is not in the regular ascii. It could have been one of the first characters, which are not printable. For instance, End-of-line is in the ASCII.

What happens if you transfer your file from windows to linux? Will the EOF file character be automatically updated?

Comment: This seems much more as new questions than a real answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 getchar()
```

gets a character from input.

```
 c = getchar()
```

The value of this assignment is the value of the left side after the assignment, or the value of the character that's been read. Value of `EOF` is by default `-1`.

```
 ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

As long as the value stays something other than `EOF` or, in other words, as long as the condition stays true, the loop will continue to iterate. Once the value becomes `EOF` the value of the entire condition will be `0` and it will break the loop.

The additional parentheses around `c = getchar()` are for the compiler, to emphasize that we really wanted to do an assignment inside the condition, because it usually assumes you wanted to type `==` and warns you.

```
 main() {
     int c;
     while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
         putchar(c);
 }
```

So the entire code actually echoes back what you input. It assigns the value of the characters to `c` inside the condition and then outputs it back in the body of the loop, ending only when the end of file is detected.

Comment: The additional parentheses around c = getchar() are for the compiler, to emphasize that we do not want to assign the result of getchar() != EOF.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar manner to the | pipe command above you can use redirection on your system to utilize the above code to display all the character contents of a file, till it reaches the end (EOF) represented by CTRL-Z or CTRL-D usually.

In console:
`ProgramName < FileName1.txt`

And to create a copy of what is read from FileName1 you can: 
`ProgramName < FileName1.txt > CopyOfInput.txt`

This demonstrates your program in multiple ways to hopefully aid your understanding.

-Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
main(){
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
   putchar(c);
}
```

Actually c=getchar() provides the character which user enters on the console and that value is checked with EOF which represents End Of File . EOF is encountered at last of file. (c = getchar()) != EOF is equivalent to c != EOF . Now i think this is much easier . If you any further query let me know.

Answer (score 0):

why has no one said yet that `int getchar(void)` returns the next input character each time it is called or **EOF** when it encounters end of file? That's the truth though and it is not out of the subject!