# Splitting a string with strtok() goes wrong

Tags: c, malloc, clang, realloc, strtok

I'm trying to get input from the user while allocating it dynamically and then "split" it using strtok.

Main Questions:

1. Im getting an infinite loop of "a{\300_\377" and ",".
2. Why do i get a warning of "Implicitly declaring library function "malloc"/"realoc" with type void"

Other less important questions:

3.i want to break, if the input includes "-1", how do i check it? As you can see it breaks now if its 1.

4.In the getsWordsArray() i want to return a pointer to an array of strings. Since i dont know how many strings there are  do i also need to dynamically allocate it like in the getInput(). (I dont know how many chars are there in each string)

```
   int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        char input = getInput();
         getWordsArray(&input);  
    }
    char getInput()
    {   
        char *data,*temp;
        data=malloc(sizeof(char));
        char c; /* c is the current character */
        int i; /* i is the counter */
        printf ("\n Enter chars and to finish push new line:\n");
        for (i=0;;i++) {
            c=getchar(); /* put input character into c */
            if (c== '1')                // need to find a way to change it to -1
                break;
            data[i]=c; /* put the character into the data array */
            temp=realloc(data,(i+1)*sizeof(char)); /* give the pointer some memory */
            if ( temp != NULL ) {
                data=temp;
            } else {
                free(data);
                printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
                return 0 ;
            }
        }   
        printf("list is: %s\n",data); // for checking
        return *data;     
    }

    void getWordsArray(char *input)
    {
        char *token;
        char *search = " ,";
        token = strtok (input,search);
        while (token != NULL ) {
            printf("%s\n",token);
            token = strtok(NULL,search);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
i noticed i forgot to "strtok" command so i changed it to `token = strtok(NULL,search);`

I still get wierd output on the printf:

```
\327{\300_\377
```

Comment: what is 'token = (NULL,search);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char input = getInput();
    getWordsArray(&input);  
}
```

to:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *input = getInput();
    getWordsArray(input);  
}
```

with a similar to the return value of `getInput()`:

```
char *getInput()
{   
    // ...
    return data;
}
```

In your code, you were only saving the first character of the input string, and then passing mostly garbage to `getWordsArray()`.

For your `malloc()` question, `man malloc` starts with:

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <stdlib.h>
```

For your `getchar()` question, perhaps see [I'm trying to understand getchar() != EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10720821/318716), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Joseph answered Q1.

Q2: `malloc` and `realoc` returns type `void *`. You need to explicitly convert that to `char *`. Try this:

```
data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Q3: 1 can be interpreted as one character. -1, while converting to characters, is equivalent to string "-1" which has character '-' and '1'. In order to check against -1, you need to use `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare against the string "-1".

Q4: If you are going to return a different copy, yes, dynamically allocate memory is a good idea. Alternatively, you can put all pointers to each token into a data structure like a linked list for future reference. This way, you avoid making copies and just allow access to each token in the string.

Comment: R.e. `data = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char))`. The cast is necessary in C++, but unnecessary and indeed frowned upon in C.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey That's why I believe it is good practice to do such explicit type conversion even in C. Though in C++, this is also deprecated so one should avoid this unless absolutely necessary, ie, while reusing huge chunk of C code.

Answer (score 1):

Things that are wrong:

1. Strings in C are null-terminated. The `%s` argument to `printf` means "just keep printing characters until you hit a `'\0'`". Since you don't null-terminate `data` before printing it, `printf` is running off the end of `data` and just printing your heap (which happens to not contain any null bytes to stop it).
2. What headers did you `#include`? Missing `<stdlib.h>` is the most obvious reason for an implicit declaration of `malloc`.
3. `getInput` returns the first `char` of `data` by value. This is not what you want. (`getWordsArray` will never work. Also see 1.)

Suggestions:

Here's one idea for breaking on -1: `if ((c == '1') && (data[i-1] == '-'))`

To get an array of the strings you would indeed need a dynamic array of `char *`. You could either `malloc` a new string to copy each `token` that `strtok` returns, or just save each `token` directly as a pointer into `input`.

Comment: Thank you, but i didnt get the first thing about the printf - what do u suggest ?

Comment: @YevgeniTarler Once you break out of the loop, you need to add one more element to the end of `data` and set that to `'\0'`. Then your `char` array becomes a valid null-terminated string.