# Determining EOF expression

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I need to verify that  the expression `getchar() ! = EOF` is `0` or `1`.
My current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    while (( c= getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        printf("%d ", c != EOF);
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", c != EOF);
}
```

When I try to run that  I get

```
98980980
1 91 81 91 81 01 91 81 01
```

I`m not sure if I got this right.

EDIT:

Ok the question was actually " How to generate EOF "
and the solution was to press ctrl+D.

Comment: You should be sure that isn't right, because you just said you have to verify if it is 1 or 0. And it isn't.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What's your input ? And what do you want ?

Comment: You should take a look [understanding getchar() != EOF] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720821/im-trying-to-understand-getchar-eof)

Comment: `c` always not equal `EOF` at inside while-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very sure if you want this answer, but as per my understanding, what information you're looking for is

- If you input any *valid character*, `getchar() != EOF` yields 1.
- If you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (on linux), or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on windows), it will generate `EOF` and `getchar() != EOF` yields 0.

Comment: Ok, I was just pressing Enter and that`s what the fuss probably was for. Many thanks

Comment: @coder111 Please be aware, pressing enter key generates a `\n`, which is not equal to `EOF`. ;-)

Comment: @coder111 , Enter==EndOfLine(`\n`), not EndOfFile(`EOF`).