# Why does the statement getchar() != EOF always return 1 in my code?

Tags: c

In my C programming book, if I do not input a real char, the statement **getchar() != EOF** will return 0. But when I practiced this principle, I found it did not make sense according to my result. My code always return 1 no matter what character I give. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{   
    printf("%d\n", getchar() != EOF);
}
```

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you, it runs correctly, but isn't space equal to end of file?

Comment: No, files can have spaces in them, so it can't be used to indicate EOF.

Comment: This is a definitive answer you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10720881/147407

Answer (score 3):

> My code always return 1 no matter what character I give.

That’s the expected behaviour: `getchar()` should *only* return `EOF` if *no* character was read. In all other cases it should return the character read, with a value ≠ `EOF`.

Comment: ... and that is why the function returns an `int` rather than a `char`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe. Unfortunately C has quite a lot of functions that operate on `char`s but accept/return `int` instead, even where this doesn’t make sense.