# Read in space delimited numbers using scanf and storing them in an array - C

Tags: c

I'm trying to take user input containing a bunch of space delimited 1-3 digit numbers using scanf() and storing them into an int array and printing each seperate one on a new line to test but it's not working. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int sourceArr[500];
  int i = 0;

  printf("\nEnter ciphertext: \n");
  while (scanf("%d", &sourceArr[i++]) == 1);
  for (int j=0;j<500;j++) {
    printf("%d\n", sourceArr[j]);
  }
}
```

so the user is asked to input a sequence of numbers like so:

```
Enter ciphertext: 
23 122 32
```

and I want to store 23 in sourceArr[0], 122 in sourceArr[1] and 32 in sourceArr[2] and then print each one like so:

```
23
122
32
```

But the program idles right after entering the input and won't print the numbers.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a sample of the input you're giving, the output you're getting, and what you expected for output. Thanks.

Comment: You should change the `for` loop to `for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++)` so you don't print more than what you read.

Answer (score 1):

On success, **scanf** returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

You could change it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int sourceArr[500];
  int i = 0;

  printf("\nEnter ciphertext: \n");
  while (scanf("%d", &sourceArr[i++]) == 1);
  for (int j=0;j<i-1;j++) {
    printf("%d\n", sourceArr[j]);
  }
}
```

Then if you enter:
1 2 3 4 5 6 x (and hit enter)

It will display as you want.

If you don't like the 'x' you could use this while line:

```
while (scanf("%d", &sourceArr[i++]) != EOF);
```

and then type something like:
12 23 345 554 (hit enter) and then (ctrl+z) in windows or (ctrl+d) in unix.

see this thread: [End of File(EOF) of Standard input stream (stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197025/end-of-fileeof-of-standard-input-stream-stdin)

ctrl+z explicitly makes scanf return EOF because the console has no EOF and needs to be sent this way.

Comment: Okay this works for single digit numbers but the numbers the user will be entering can be anywhere from 1-3 digits eg: 1, 23, 213 *in between 0 - 255* so how could I get this to work exactly?

Comment: @VAndrei: Is this the only way to solve this issue? I mean entering x at the end of the input doesn't really look good right?

Comment: No actually it works for all numbers. Not just single digits. @pala this is not the only solution. This is just the least "invasive" :)

Comment: @VAndrei can we make scanf () return EOF by giving inputs through stdin

Answer (score 1):

The `"%d"` consumes leading white-space such as `' '` and `'\n'`, not just  `' '`.

So when the user enters "123 456 789" <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `scanf()` is called again waiting for more input.  It will continue to wait until non-numeric data in entered, `stdin` is closed or rarely experiences an IO error.

Since `stdin` is usually buffered, `stdin` and `scanf()` do not see *any* input from a line until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

```
while (scanf("%d", &sourceArr[i++]) == 1);
```

If code needs to to end input with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use `fgets()` to read a *line*.  Then parse it using `sscanf()` or `strtol()`.  The below uses `"%n"` to record the number of `char` scanned.

```
char buf[100];
printf("\nEnter ciphertext: \n");
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL)
  Handle_EOF();

char *p = buf;
int n;
while (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &sourceArr[i], &n) == 1) {
  i++;
  p += n;
}

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  printf("%d\n", sourceArr[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf returns the number of items successfully scanned. Try the below code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      int sourceArr[500];
      int i = 0;
      int sc =0; //scanned items
      int n=3; // no of integers to be scanned

      printf("\nEnter ciphertext: \n");
       while(sc<n){
          sc += scanf("%d",&sourceArr[i++]);
       }
      for (int j=0;j<i;j++) {
        printf("%d\n", sourceArr[j]);
      }
    }
```