# my BufferedReader character input loop program keeps running forever

Tags: java, inputstream, infinite-loop

I wrote a program which prints out the characters of the sentence (or word) wrote by the user to the console. I thought that the program will end after I gave the first input. But it didn't and kept taking inputs and printing it even after it printed the first sentence. Can you explain me why it happened so? I am new to this. Here is the program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

/*
 * This program prints out the characters written in the console
 * line by line.
 */
public class ReaderProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        char c;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        do{
            //reads character and stores it in c
            c = (char) br.read();
            //prints out c
            System.out.println(c);
        }while(c != -1);
        //'while' checks if c is -1 (-1 means end of the stream)
    }
}
```

Output is shown here (Input to console is show like ***this***):

***Epic***
E
p
i
c
    
    
    
    
***Dream***
D
r
e
a
m

Comment: Explain us why you think it should stop. Use the javadoc of Reader.read() to help you. Also think about the following points: what is the end of the System.in stream? What is the range of values of a char?

Comment: The `System.in` stream does not normally end, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197025/end-of-fileeof-of-standard-input-stream-stdin .

Comment: @HannoBinder excellent point, br.read() will be blocking for that reason.  I missed that.  The code had two problems with it.  Add that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have cast the result of `br.read()` too early.

`br.read()` returns a `int`, which has a larger storage capacity than a `char`. `char` is neither signed nor large enough to store both `-1` and the full UTF-16 range of values.

By casting the result to a `char` before comparing it to `-1` you have effectively converted -1 to `Character.MAX_VALUE`.  Which can never equal `-1`.

Consider the following code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    char v = (char) -1;
    System.out.println( "v = " + (int) v );
}
```

It will print `65535`, and not `-1`.