# How to avoid spaces, enter key or non-numeric input in C ? scanf reads integer value

Tags: c, do-while

Get input untill it's an integer beetween 0 and 23.

```
int n;    
do
{
    printf("Enter height: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
} while ( n < 0 || n > 23);
```

adding `EOF` and `NULL` to while somehow?

Comment: Check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Comment: `between 0 and 24` and `while ( n < 0 || n > 23)`...something is _off_.

Comment: Don't use `scanf`at all but use `fgets` and parse the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I see is that the input '24' itself won't stop the loop, so you need to change the condition to:

```
while ( n < 0 || n > 24);
```

NULL is not an issue, as you can't get NULL from stdin. NULL means an address that points byte number 0. It won't happen, as you call scanf with a memory that is on the stack of the current running thread.

about EOF from stdin, you can get more info here 
[End of File(EOF) of Standard input stream (stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197025/end-of-fileeof-of-standard-input-stream-stdin).

About using scanf, I would recommend to read:
[Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

---

**EDIT:** This is what's best to do. Get rid of scanf and use fgets and strtol, like the following example (taken from [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583717/how-to-scanf-only-integer))

```
char *end;
char buf[LINE_MAX];
int n = 0;

do {
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        break;

    // remove \n
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';

    //Get integer from line
    n = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
 // making sure that a valid input was given (i.e. a number) and its value
 // You might also want to check that strlen(end) is zero, to avoid input like "213 abcde", depends on you
} while ((end != buf) && ( (n > 24 || n < 0)));
```

Comment: my problem is that I don’t know how to ask for input again when I got  " ", "abc" or enter key. it loops