# c: reading input with while(scanf()==1) isn't leaving the loop

Tags: c, scanf

I'm reading from stdin into an array input[], but it never leaves the loop after reading the input and keeps expecting more input. What am I doing wrong?

```
        char input[1000];
        while(scanf("%s",input)==1){
            printf("%s\n",input);
        }
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469643/value-returned-by-scanf-function-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197025/end-of-fileeof-of-standard-input-stream-stdin

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned. `%s` matches a sequence of non-white-space characters, aka your first word, but leaves the newline `\n` in the buffer. `scanf` returns 1. After that it reads the newline and returns one, then you input a second word, etc etc etc. You see the loop?

Comment: Should have an OS tag here.

Comment: What do you want the user to type to indicate the end of input?

Answer (score 0):

What you expect, how do you try to terminate it? `scanf("%s",  input)` keeps waiting input always and always returns 1 if `stdin` is life, it skips whitespaces and matches the first char sequence without whitespaces. Please read the manual carefully.

If you want to continue `scanf` using then you should provide a special string for breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since `scanf()` returns **the number of elements successfully read, you must find a way to make it fail to read the `%s`. One common practice is to end the input with EOF, which is `Ctrl-Z` then `Enter` in Windows console, and `Ctrl-D` on a Unix terminal. After reading EOF `scanf()` will return `EOF` which is of course not 1, then the loop exits normally.

Alternatively, you can use a custom terminating string in your code:

```
    char input[1000];
    while (scanf("%s", input) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(input, "end") == 0) {
            // End the loop
            break;
        }
        printf("%s\n", input);
    }
```