# istream_iterator copy example keeps waiting for input

Tags: c++, std, istream-iterator

I tried implementing an example of stream iterators from page 107 of "The C++ Standard Library". I get stuck on this line:

```
copy (istream_iterator<string>(cin), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(coll));
```

The program keeps reading data from the console here, but does not pass on to the next line. How do I continue past this point?

Comment: Ctrl+Z worked. Thanks.

Comment: If one of the answers answered your question, you can [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/218012) by clicking on the check mark. If they didn't answer your question, can you comment to elaborate on what you are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take for instance, if you would have made an input stream of int then you would have given input like - 45 56 45345 555 ....., so in all those cases, the reading operation of input stream would have returned a true value - `while (cin>>var) { }`
the while statement will not stop if it is getting a valid input, so to stop the reading of characters, we gave it following input, ... 54 56 3545 | , and as soon as it receives a special character the while loop stops as the conditions returns false.

That's the same case for all other type of input streams as well.

So I assume you understand here why your string type input stream never stops taking input because every possible input can be considered string.

The solution to this problem is using "ctrl + D in UNIX" and "ctrl + Z in windows", as it gives NULL in condition of while loop which means false, hence stoping the reading of string input.

Comment: This answer is hard to follow. From a brief skim, I believe in the first paragraph, you are saying that this behavior is no different from what happens when you write `while (cin >> var) {}`, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: "as it appends a NULL which returns false" is wrong in so many ways. It "appends" an EOF, which is different from NUL, which is different from NULL, which doesn't "return false"

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments, I will work harder on my vocabulary from next time.

Comment: You could always try to edit this answer to address what I mentioned. Vocabulary isn't necessarily the problem, though. That first paragraph could use some formatting, for example, and it's a bit too wordy - it's a run-on sentence. As for the last part which is wrong, you can absolutely correct that as well.

Answer (score 3):

[From cppreference:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)

> The default-constructed `std::istream_iterator` is known as the
>   *end-of-stream* iterator. When a valid `std::istream_iterator` **reaches the
>   end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the *end-of-stream***
>   iterator. Dereferencing or incrementing it further invokes undefined
>   behavior

<sup>bold added</sup>

In other words, `std::istream_iterator<string>(std::cin)` keeps going until the end-of-input for `std::cin`. This doesn't happen at the end of the line, but at the *end-of-file.* In a console, there are [specific commands to trigger the EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3197123):

> In UNIX systems it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, in Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.