# How to input 2 strings with specific size in a row handling strings with longer length in c?

Tags: c, scanf, buffer-overflow

I want to read two strings from input like the code below. The problem is when the user enters a string with a longer size that causes overflow. for example if user enters "steven" as name[0], the second scanf() won't work and the result is name[0]="stev" and name[1]="en".
My desired output is name[0]="stev" and name[1] be at most the 4 characters read using second scanf(), for example name[1]="gabr" if the input is gabriel.
I tried fflush(stdin) before second scanf() and also fgets instead of scanf but none of them helped.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[2][5];
    printf("Enter name1: \n");
    scanf("%4s", name[0]);
    //fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter name2: \n");
    scanf("%4s", name[1]);
    for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++)
        printf("You entered: %s\n", name[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

anyone can help me with this please?

Comment: You could use `scanf("%4s %*[^\n]%*c", name[0]);` but it's not safe to any possible input.

Comment: You cannot use `scanf` for interactive user input apart for test and toy programs. Consider using `fgets` and parse the resulting string yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use `fgets` instead of `scanf`, like this:

`fgets( name[0], 5, stdin );`

That way, you can check whether a newline was consumed by `fgets` (`scanf` does not provide this information) and if not, consume the rest of the line:

```
int len = strlen( name[0] );
if ( len > 0 && name[0][len-1] != '\n' )
{
    //a newline was not read by fgets, so we must consume the
    //rest of the line up to and including the '\n' character
    int c;

    while ( ( c = fgetc( stdin) ) != EOF && c != '\n' );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I also used the below line after each scanf and got what i wanted.
while((getchar()) != '\n');

Comment: @AmirhosseinBigdeli: Yes, that should also work. However, if [EOF is read from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3197025/12149471) (caused for example by piping stdin or the user manually entering EOF), then you may have an infinite loop. Therefore, checking for EOF is generally safer. But this is only a minor issue. I believe most implementations only return EOF once if it is manually entered by the user.

Comment: @AmirhosseinBigdeli: Generally, I wouldn't recommend using `scanf`, unless you know exactly what you are doing. You may want to read this guide: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)