# Extracting an individual char and an individual int from an inputted string containing an int and char?

Tags: c

I am creating my first project - a chess game. Right now, I have the program ask the user for a row and then a column, like so:

```
White move.
column: F
row: 3
```

However, I would like to make this a bit more seamless, so that it looks like the following:

```
White move.
Input: F3
```

Then, it takes the 'F' and puts it in a variable, and takes the '3' and puts that in a separate variable. I see solutions to this in other languages, but I don't see it for C. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to write code to do this; you do not appear (based on what was posted) to have attempted to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a basic `scanf` :

```
char c;
int i;
scanf("%c%d", &c, &i);
printf("column\t%c\nrow\t%d\n", c, i);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was separating this into two separate scanf functions (one for an int and one for a char), and I did not know you could do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @limserhane is perfectly fine. I just wanted to let you know that is better if you put a space before `%c` to discard any space in the buffer that can be there either because of a typo from the user or because you didn't fully read previous inputs.

And you should also care about possible errors from the user, looping the `scanf` until you don't get a valid input.

```
while( scanf(" %c%d", &c, &i) != 2 || c < 'A' || c > 'Z' || i < 1 || i > 8 ) puts("Invalid coordinates, please try again.");
```

And also mind to clear the buffer in case the user entered more than you could read with `%c%d`

```
while( scanf(" %c%d", &c, &i) != 2 || c < 'A' || c > 'Z' || i < 1 || i > 8 ) {

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n'); // clear the buffer

    puts("Invalid coordinates, please try again.");
}
```

Comment: Note: `while( scanf(" %c%d", &c, &i) != 2 ||  ...` is an infinite loop on end-fo-file.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why are you saying that? It stops when the user enter for example `A 1`

Comment: "when the user enter for example A 1" is not an "end-of-file" condition.  When `stdin` is closed ([end-of-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3197025/2410359)), `scanf()` continually returns `EOF`, hence an infinite loop.

Comment: But the user need to enter the end-of-file. Nobody told him to do that

Comment: Best to not assume user input is as expected.  Robust code handles all sorts of user inputs,  detects problems and reports them.  It depends on how resilient your want the code to be.

Comment: Yes but the end-of-file in stdin would be a sentinel value used to say "I'm done". Since the program doesn't mention any sentinel value, why shouldn't the program treat the end-of-file as an invalid input?

Comment: "end-of-file in stdin would be a sentinel value used to say "I'm done". "  --> but code does not end the loop on end-of-file.  The code here `while( scanf(" %c%d", &c, &i) != 2 ...` repeatedly calls `scanf()` when `scanf()` returns `EOF` due to end-of-file and  that is not 2.  Then subsequent calls also return `EOF` --> infinite loop.

Comment: Then I should treat `A 1 @` as a correct input as well. Because the user may think that `@` is a sentinel value, even though the program never said anything about that.